# Ошибки в среде разработки при работе с Unity

Tags: unity3d

После переустановки ОС установил Unity Hub, далее unity и visual studio, unity работает, создаю скрипт, открываю и сразу летят ошибки про отсутствующие скобки. Visual studio не дает подсказки про синтаксис юнити. Попробовал подключить Sublime Text и все равно ошибки. Юнити не запускает проект из-за этих ошибок. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Юнити и визуал студио переустанавливал, пробовал удалять все файлы с юнити и визуал студии.[image: Ошибка в юнити]
[image: пример кода]

В коде вообще не важно что пишу, даже если ставлю пробел и удаляю, сразу появляются эти ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Свойства класса **с модификатором доступа** пишутся **вне методов**.

А **переменные методов** - **без** модификаторов доступа

Comment: *В коде вообще не важно что пишу, даже если ставлю пробел и удаляю, сразу появляются эти ошибки. Я указал, что вообще не важно, что написано в коде, даже чистый, вновь созданный скрипт кидает ошибки. У меня есть сохраненные старые проекты, все рабочие, и ранее в них все четко работало. Сейчас такая же беда. Открыл скрипт, он сразу помечается ошибками. Не видит скобки вообще, если между ними хотя бы даже пробел поставить. И синтаксис с# не подтягивает визуал студио.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, спасибо за совет добрым людям. Переустановил юнити без визуал студио. Визуал установил отдельно с офф сайта( а не из юнити хаб), предварительно поудалял все папки с остатками визуал студио от предыдущих установок.